# Why does $P(E) < P(F)$ imply that $E \subseteq F$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Why does $P(E) < P(F)$ mean that $E \subseteq F$ ?

**My reasoning** (using Venn diagrams):

It is seen clearly in the below picture that even if $P(E)<P(F)$, there is still some region in E that is not a part of F, So why is $E \subseteq F$ true?

[image]

**Source if this information**

Solution for a question from JEE Advanced 1998

Question:
[image]

Solution:
[image]

Comment: It doesn't, clearly.  Perhaps you left off some assumptions?

Comment: @lulu I've edited the question with the source of my confusion

Comment: @MariaMazur edited the question

Comment: @MariaMazur from where did the first statement come?

Comment: It is wrong solution.

Comment: Ohkay @MariaMazur . Thanks for the clarification

Comment: The answer is certainly correct.  That is, $D$ is the only choice which holds in general.  You've edited out parts of their reasoning which certainly does seem a bit hard to follow.

Comment: That is the most poorly worded solution that I have seen.  It seems like a false argument for (A),(B),(C) before the final correct statement "Therefore, (D) is the Ans."

Comment: @lulu this was the complete solution. I got the answer using counterexamples, but was confused with the statements in the solution

Comment: Well, if that's all they wrote then I agree, it's incomprehensible.  Your approach is entirely correct.  Just construct counterexamples to each of the other options and then you are left with "none of the above".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is false.

Consider cossing two coins. Write $H$ when we get a head and $T$ when we get tail. Then

$\Omega := \{(H,H),(H,T),(T,T),(T,H)\}$

Then $P(\{(H,H)\}) = 1/4 < P(\{(T,T),(T,H)\}) = 1/2$

yet

$$\{(H,H)\} \not\subseteq \{(T,T),(T,H)\}$$

Comment: I've edited the question with the source

Comment: What exactly is the question? I gave a counterexample for the claim you proposed.

Comment: I was confused as the statement was given in a solution. Even I wasn't sure if it was true. Now, MariaMazur had clarified in the comments that the solution is wrong. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Yes, the solution seems wrong. A weird reasoning for sure.